# How to prevent SQL injection in getContentResolver().query?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a code:

```
private static Cursor getQuery(Context context, Uri uri) {   
    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, QUERY_SELECT, null, null, null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        cursor.moveToNext();
    } else {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
            cursor = null;
        }
    }
    return cursor;
}
private static final String[] QUERY_SELECT = new String[]{
            _ID,
            _NAME
    };
```

And i get this error:

> sql_not_constant: SQL string QUERY_SELECT is not a constant literal. Passing the tainted command to the content provider API android.content.ContentResolver.query(android.net.Uri, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String, java.lang.String[], java.lang.String) may allow an attacker to inject SQL.

It show me 3 suggestion:

> 1. Validate user-supplied values against predefined constant values. Pass these values to the content provider.
> 2. Parameterize the selection using ? positional characters. Bind the ? positional parameters using the selectionArgs argument.
> 3. Insert tainted values into the content provider by first storing them in ContentValues.

Anyone else help me with this?

Comment: Show the definition of `QUERY_SELECT`.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- i showed it in my post.